# Did I calculate the Image of this matrix correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Calculate the image of the matrix $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1  &  2 & -1\\ 
> -2 & -6 & 1 \\  1  & -2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$

First I transposed the matrix:

$A^{T}= \begin{pmatrix}
1  &  -2 &  1 \\ 
2  &  -6 & -2 \\ 
-1 &   1 &  0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Then I used Gauss to get zero lines. Multiply first line  with $2$, add that to second line:

$A^{T}= \begin{pmatrix}
2  &  -4 & 2\\ 
4  & -10 & 0 \\ 
-1 &   1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Now multiply third line with $10$ and add second line to third line:

$A^{T}= \begin{pmatrix}
2  &  -4 & 2\\ 
4  & -10 & 0 \\ 
-6 &   0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

We cannot create more zeroes, so Gauss ends here. We transpose back:

$A= \begin{pmatrix}
 2  &   4 & -6 \\ 
-4  & -10 &  0 \\ 
 2  &   0 &  0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus we have $\text{Img(A)}= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
-4\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
4\\ 
-10\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
-6\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} \right\}$

---

It's very important for me to know, did I do it correctly? I would do it like this in my exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a highly unusual method.  However, it is technically correct.  You have indeed found a basis of the image.  Remember to say that the image is the **span** of those vectors.

Comment: Thank you for answer! How would it look like with this span?

Comment: You just have to say something like: thus we have $$\text{Img(A)}= \operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
-4\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
4\\ 
-10\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
-6\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} \right\}\right)$$
And in fact, this is just all of $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: Sorry for a further question but I have just realized that in language; you said "unusual method". It sounds like I took a long, time consuming way. Maybe you can share a usual way that is easier and faster, if there is one? If it's too long to write, never mind it, this helped a lot already :)

Comment: You didn't do anything particularly difficult or slow. It's just that usually when people "do Gauss", they start by making zeros on the left side.

Comment: Oh alright. I usually do it like that as well but in this example the zero was annoying, it was on the bottom right corner :p So just to be sure; If I leave "span" away, then I have a basis of the image. If I write span(..), I have an image of the matrix, right?

Comment: That's right. If you leave "span" out, then you have a basis of the image. If you write span(..), then you have the image of the matrix.